# How to pass modules inputs while calling it from index.js file

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

I am building some custom plugins for a product that uses proprietary npm module to setup connection and perform an operation(read, write and submit) on mainframe emulator.

I am setting up connection in index.js file and want to pass terminal variable to separate module while calling it

index.js snippet

```
    var terminal;
    const mainframeTerminal =require(‘private_module’);
    const accountDetailsModule =require('./src/accountDetails');

    terminal = private_module.connect('11.11.11.1:789');
    let screen = await terminal.status();
    // expose module from index.js file so that it can be consumes in product
    export.getAccountDetails = accountDetailsModule.getAccountDetails(terminal)
```

accountDetails.js

```
module.exports.getAccountDetails = async function(terminal){   
    //perform some operation with termianl var - passed from index file
    return data;
    }
```

I am getting below error 
exports.getAccountDetails = accountDetailsModule.getAccountDetails is not a function.
I also need to pass data input but for the time being it's not required, 
Would like to know how node.js function will understand mapping if I just need to pass anyone of input only.

Please throw some inputs, I am new to coding.

Comment: I don't know but maybe `export.getAccountDetails` should be `exports.getAccountDetails`.

Comment: sorry that was typo error, its exports

Answer (score 0):

like this

**index.js**

```
const mainframeTerminal =require('private_module');
const accountDetailsModule = require('./src/accountDetails');

const terminal = private_module.connect('11.11.11.1:789');
let screen = await terminal.status();

// expose module from index.js
exports = accountDetailsModule(terminal);
```

**accountDetails.js**

```
const getAccountDetails = async (terminal) => {
    // perform some operation
    return data;
}

exports = getAccountDetails;
```

In [CommonJS](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html#modules_modules), modules are just a way to assign variables. So what you get in index.js when you `require('./src/accountDetails')` is exactly what you export in accountDetails.js (the value of `getAccountDetails`, which is an async function taking one argument).

**runMyCode.js**

Here's how you might call your code...

```
const mainframeTerminal =require('private_module');
const accountDetailsModule = require('./src/accountDetails');

const terminal = private_module.connect('11.11.11.1:789');
let screen = await terminal.status();

// run the code a print the result to console
accountDetailsModule(terminal).then(console.log);
```

Comment: how are you calling your code? Is index.js meant to be a module that you import, or your application code? If the latter, you don't need or want an exports statement. see `runMyCode.js` above